# How to Change Data to Something Else If True in a Column? MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a column which currently contains a list of countries. 
I want to change all those countries to the capital of the country. 
So for example; data where there is France listed on rows, I want to change all those to Paris instead.

Comment: please show your table data

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: @Tanner No need to provide a negative comment like that. Not everyone is an SQL expert. If I could have found it, I would have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a table where the data inside a column is the name of the country and you want this column to hold the capital city of that country instead, right?

```
UPDATE your_table
SET column = 'Paris'
WHERE Column = 'France'

UPDATE your_table
SET column = 'London'
WHERE Column = 'England'

UPDATE your_table
SET column = 'Washington DC'
WHERE Column = 'USA'
```

**Additional**

Instead of writing multiple Update statements.  It can get quite tedious if you have rows relating to 50 countries that need to amending to show capital cities.

You can create a new table [CountryCapitalCity] with two columns.
One for CountryName and the other for CapitalCity and then write one UPDATE statement, using a SET BASED approach, joining to the new table.

```
UPDATE YT
    --ColumnToUpdate holds CountryName data instead of Capital City
SET ColumnToUpdate = CC.CapitalCity --Update that Column to CapitalCity from the new table
FROM your_table YT
INNER JOIN CountryCapitalCity CC ON CC.CountryName = YT.ColumnToUpdate
```